# Access controller variable directly inside component class - Laravel

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-7

Normally we pass the parameter from controller into x component like `<x-book-list books="$books" />` and access it in BookList Class as below

```php
namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class BookList extends Component
{
    public $books;
    
    /**
     * BookList Component
     *
     * @param array $book
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $books)
    {
        $this->books = $books;
    }
```

I use this kind of component in my app repeatedly but here, I want to make it a bit cleaner without adding `books` attribute every-time I call it because they are definitely the same everywhere.

So, can I access the `books variable` inside Book component class without passing through `<x-book-list />`?

Probably something as below.

```php
namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class BookList extends Component
{
    public $books;
    
    /**
     * BookList Component
     *
     * @param array $book
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // How to access $book variable directly from controller without passing from <x-booklist /> ????
    }
```

Comment: create a book component that extends component pass that variable to contructor and use the parent constructor in every extended component of your book component

Comment: @bhucho Would you answer this question with sample codes? So that people come here later can see it or I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just addd the property as tag like:

```
<x-my-component
:variable="$variable"
/>
```

MyComponent.php
...

```
class MyComponent extends Component
{
    public $variable;

    public function __construct($variable)
    {
        $this->variable= $variable;
    }
}
```

and thats all

Comment: Suppose that I'm using this same components `<x-my-component :variable="$variable" />` in 50 controllers and 100 view files, I'll have to pass that variable from all 50 controllers to 100 components. It seems very repetitive. I was looking for the clean way without passing the variables like `<x-my-component />` and just get that $variable inside `MyComponent` class.

Comment: oh, if variable is static, you can get it like ClassController::getmyvarible()

Comment: @ronaldtgi i foundd another way cool -> on your controller -> \View::share('periodName', $periodName); // then in your component -->> $data = \View::getShared();  -->> $data['periodName']

Comment: @ronaldtgi a declarative approach to programming is far easier to understand and manage. You don't generally want inherited logic and variables inside your classes. Let's say for example you (or someone else) come back to that component 2 years down the track. The first question will be - where the fuck is this variable value coming from?

Passing the value, although repetitive, will result in cleaner code, and easier to manage projects, for anyone that works on it.